# Upload docker image gitlab ci/cd Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

```
java-build:
  tags:
    - docker-in-docker
  image: maven:3.8-openjdk-11
  services:
    - docker:20.10.13-dind-alpine3.15

  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn clean package
```

Hello guys , this is my `yaml` where i try to build java spring image , now i wanto to upload in DockerHub , what is best way ? when i try

```
- echo "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u $DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin
- docker push $DOCKER_IMAGE:latest
```

there is error ,  can not find docker ... i know beacuse i am using  `image: maven:3.8-openjdk-11` ... what is best way? to upload this build ?

Answer (score 0):

If the error is "Cannot find docker" it means docker-cli is not installed in your environment.
Install it and try again.